# Converting PyObject* to C++ Object

Tags: python, c++, type-conversion, boost-python, pyobject

I have a shared library (util.so) that returns the following to python:

```
cv::Mat toCvMat(PyObject *ndArrayObj) {
    // return cv::Mat
}
```

I invoke the method from my python script using:

**Python:**

```
testMat = util.toCvMat(orig_frame_gray_img)
```

When I pass this to my other test library (test_library.so), it is passed as PyObject*, how do I access cv::Mat in my test_library.so?:

**Python:**

```
test_library.process(testMat)
```

**C++**

```
bool TestLibrary::Process( PyObject* pTestImg)
{
// How to get cv::Mat from pTestImg?
}
```

At present, my test_library doesn't link with util and they are separate .so files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on http://yati-sagade.github.io/2013/05/11/numpy-boost-python/

```
NDArrayConverter cvt;
cv::Mat m;
m = cvt.toMat(pTestImg);
```

The required `NDArrayConverter` can be found from https://github.com/yati-sagade/opencv-ndarray-conversion